# Does switch statement start comparing cases from the top in this example?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I found this example to make range work with switch statement:

```
function GetText(value)
{
    var result;

    switch (true)
    {
        case ((value >= 26) && (value <= 50)):
            result = ">= 26.";
            break;

        case ((value >= 1) && (value <= 25)):
            result = "Between 1 and 25.";
            break;

        case (value == 0):
            result = "Equals Zero.";
            break;

    }

    return result;
}
```

But if I modify the code and remove the second check for the value the example will still work:

```
function GetText(value)
{
    var result;

    switch (true)
    {
        case ((value >= 26)):
            result = ">= 26 .";
            break;

        case ((value >= 1)):
            result = "Between 1 and 25.";
            break;

        case (value == 0):
            result = "Equals Zero.";
            break;

    }

    return result;
}
```

So if I passed 29 even that I have two `true` cases the first one will be selected. My question is that how switch statement works in most of programming languages it will start comparing from the top or its only in this case (and is it good or bad to write it like that?).

Comment: Why in the world are you using a `switch` for this?

Comment: Yes, the evaluation order is from top to bottom. `break` stops the evaluation.

Comment: @Blender: actually I have never seen such idiom but I find it quite readable and interesting, +1. And yes, they are evaluated from top to bottom.

Comment: Check what will happen if you enter 51

Comment: `switch` is not intended to do this kind of stuff... but this is kind of interesting, never see it used like this.

Comment: @Blender: Why not? can you provide a better example. I have around 10 cases and I found using switch statement is more compact than a series of if statements.

Comment: @Siva Charan: Yeah I just forgot to edit the last result text. Thanks

Comment: I prefer a series of `if` and `else if` statements because: 1. You don't need to wrap it all inside a `switch`; 2. You don't need to put colons after the condition neither `break;` inside of each `if` statement; 3. IMO the syntax is easier to read and less likely to commit a typo (such as forgetting a `:` or `break`). The only drawback is having to use curly braces `{}` if you have more than one line to execute inside your `if`, but that's what makes it more readable for me. I guess it's mostly a personal preference issue not to be discussed here, but your approach is interesting nonetheless.

Comment: Never seen that idiom before either. FYI, the construct works in PHP as well (had to check it out of curiosity :)

Comment: No problem, Blender actually posted a sample code below. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`switch` statement checks for matches from top to bottom.

From [MDN docs on switch statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch):

> If a match is found, the program executes the associated statements. If multiple cases match the provided value, the first case that matches is selected, even if the cases are not equal to each other.

Comment: Thanks I'll accept your answer. In general do you think using this or a series of if statements will be better (for more than 10 cases)?

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this (with `if` and `else if` chains):

```
function GetText(value) {
    var result;

    if (value == 0) {
        result = "Equals Zero.";
    } else if (value <= 25) {
        result = "Between 1 and 25.";
    } else if (value <= 50) {
        result = "Between 26 and 50.";
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: `else if (value <= 50):` a `:` instead of `{`? +1 when you fix that.